# How to fix reCaptcha in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha, contact-form-7

I have a WP site that is getting a lot of spams lately.
I have added firewall (plugins) to help combat this.
But then decided to add an extra layer of protection (since the firewall is not working fully) by adding recaptcha.

When I tried using V3, the contact form (7) doesnt work.
Upon using the v2,it works.

But I found out that the spams are coming from a multi-step contact form, wherein I ask the user to add their email, their requirments, etc.

PS: Adding a screenshot of the contact form code for better understanding
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSJOM.png)

I tried adding the [recaptcha] shortcode on the final step, but it doesnt work.

Do you know how to fix this issue so the form can have recaptcha, and hence, less spams?

Answer (score 0):

Ever since Contact Form 7 version 5.1.  The developer decided that ReCaptcha V3 was the best method to use.  I personally disagree with this, and his forcing users to switch.

If you add this plugin [ReCaptcha v2 for Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcf7-recaptcha/) then you'll be able to configure the `[recaptcha]` form tag to work as it used to, and it will be the "I am not a robot" checkbox.